# Sort array of objects by nested property with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects like this

`[{ ‘a’: { id: 4 }}, { ‘b’: { id: 3 }}, { ‘c’: { id: 2 }}, { ‘d’: { id: 5 }}]`

I want to know with lodash the sorting of the objects according to the id. I would expect to receive something like `[‘d’, ‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’]`.

I tried to search this but I didn’t find an answer which works with different keys in each object. I tried to do this with lodash’ different functions (many). So I thought there may be a good and maybe short way to solve this.

Comment: In the first step, transform your array to `[{key: 'a', id: 4}, {key: 'b', id: 3}, …]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a plain JavaScript solution.

Since you want to get the sorted keys as the result, this solution does not modify the original array, thanks to the first `map` before `sort`:

```js
const data = [{ 'a': { id: 4 }}, { 'b': { id: 3 }}, { 'c': { id: 2 }}, { 'd': { id: 5 }}];

const sorted = data
  .map(x => Object.entries(x)[0])
  .sort((a, b) => b[1].id - a[1].id)
  .map(x => x[0]);
  
console.log(sorted);
```

If you don't care about mutating the original array, you can directly sort using `Object.values()` and then return the first key with `Object.keys()`:

```js
const data = [{ 'a': { id: 4 }}, { 'b': { id: 3 }}, { 'c': { id: 2 }}, { 'd': { id: 5 }}];

const sorted = data
  .sort((a, b) => Object.values(b)[0].id - Object.values(a)[0].id)
  .map(x => Object.keys(x)[0]);
  
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do it with javascript by using `sort` method and mapping over the returned array and returning the keys

```js
var data = [{ 'a': { id: 4 }}, { 'b': { id: 3 }}, { 'c': { id: 2 }}, { 'd': { id: 5 }}]

const res = data.sort((a, b)  => Object.values(b)[0].id - Object.values(a)[0].id).map(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0]);

console.log(res);
```

Or you can use lodash with orderBy and map methods

```js
    var data = [{ 'a': { id: 4 }}, { 'b': { id: 3 }}, { 'c': { id: 2 }}, { 'd': { id: 5 }}]

    const res = _.orderBy(data, function(a) {
      return Object.values(a)[0].id
    }, ['desc']).map(o => Object.keys(o)[0])
    
    console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same solution as what @CodeManiac already posted

Comment: @Bergi The time of post doesn't have much difference if you see and its entirely possible for two people to be working on the snippet simulatenously and posting the same answer because that is a very standard way of solving it

Answer (score 1):

You can first sort based on id and than map the key.

```js
let obj = [{ 'a': { id: 4 }}, { 'b': { id: 3 }}, { 'c': { id: 2 }}, { 'd': { id: 5 }}]

let op = obj
        .sort((a,b) => Object.values(b)[0].id - Object.values(a)[0].id)
        .map(e => Object.keys(e)[0])

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) version of [jo_va's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54853281/5157454).

Use `_.flow()` to create a function that maps each object to a `[key, { id }]` pair. Sort with `_.orderBy()` according to `id`. Iterate with `_.map()` and dxtract the `_.head()` (the key):

```js
const { flow, flatMap, toPairs, orderBy, map, head } = _

const fn = flow(
  flatMap(toPairs), // convert each object to pair of [key, { id }]
  orderBy(['[1].id'], ['desc']), // order descending by the id
  map(head) // extract the original key
)

const data = [{ 'a': { id: 4 }}, { 'b': { id: 3 }}, { 'c': { id: 2 }}, { 'd': { id: 5 }}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{ a: { id: 4 }}, { b: { id: 3 }}, { c: { id: 2 }}, { d: { id: 5 }}];
data.sort((a, b) => Object.values(b)[0].id - Object.values(a)[0].id);
console.log(data);
```

The above snippet shows how to do it with Array.sort. Lodash should work similarly.